# Edimax EW-7811un driver: wext or nl80211?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch, driver, networkmanager

I am trying to **use `wpa_supplicant`**. I see in `wpa_supplicant --help` that there are four options for its driver parameter (`-D`):

```
drivers:
  nl80211 = Linux nl80211/cfg80211
  wext = Linux wireless extensions (generic)
  wired = Wired Ethernet driver
  none = no driver (RADIUS server/WPS E
```

I have an **Edimax  EW-7811UN**, a seemingly popular WiFi dongle for Rasp Pis. Since I wasn't sure which driver it has, I tried:

```
readlink /sys/class/net/wlan4/device/driver
```

The answer I get:

```
../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu
```

**Is this `wext` or `nl80211`?**

I am on RPi 3 with Stretch (but I guess that doesn't change anything).

Comment: Accessorily, I see that `rt18192` is deprecated. Should I replace it? Source: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

Comment: Have you tried letting the system decide? ISTR the 7811UN has been supported OOTB since 2012 and needed no manual changes apart from a standard wpa_supplicant.conf

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two types of driver. The driver for the firmware (rtl8192cu) of the wifi device has nothing to do with the driver backend of *wpa_supplicant* (nl80211). Let's explain in detail.

Behind the link you have given it is said:

> Make sure to blacklist the older rtl8192cu driver, which some distros seem to load by default otherwise.

Seems Raspbian is one of these distros so you should follow it. Before doing it we have to check that the new rtl8xxxu driver is available. You can do it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo modprobe configs
rpi ~$ zcat /proc/config.gz | less
```

In the pager search for `CONFIG_RTL8` and you will find `CONFIG_RTL8XXXU=m` that means the wanted driver is compiled with the default kernel and available as module. Just try to boot with blacklisted `rtl8192cu` and look what driver is loaded. Maybe you have explicitly to load `rtl8xxxu`. I suppose you know how to do it with files in `/etc/modprobe.d`. But just looking there from a default raspbian image I see:

```
rpi ~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d/
blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf  blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf  ipv6.conf
```

Seems both drivers are already disabled. I don't know why do you see that `rtl8192cu` is loaded on your RasPi. Just restore `blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf` and rename `blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf` maybe to `blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf~`. This should load the new driver `rtl8xxxu` on boot.

Now to come to the driver backends for *wpa_supplicant*. Within `man wpa_supplicant` you will find:

> AVAILABLE DRIVERS
>   [..] Support for each of the driver backends is chosen at wpa_supplicant compile  time. For a list of supported driver backends that may be used with the -D option on your system, refer to the help output of wpa_supplicant (wpa_supplicant -h).

`wext` is the predecessor of `nl80211` and mostly only used for backward compatibility. Default is `nl80211` and you should use it at the first place with the option `-D`, for example with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0 -B
```

This is the default setting for running wpa_supplicant on Raspbian so you haven't to worry about it.

Comment: although both drivers are blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/` `rtl8192cu` is loaded.  Renaming `blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf`  has no effect. Any guess how else to activate `rtl8xxxu`?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with overlays then. Just for testing try to unload and load the drivers by hand with `sudo rmmod rtl8192cu` and `sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu`. Maybe you have also to unload/load dependend modules.

Comment: Does not work. It kills my access point. I think I’ll just stick to `rtl8192cu`. Thanks